# how save some no of trail item owned offline after that go for in app purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I want to give user 10 trails to create a PDF file for a work, After that user have to purchase **subscription** . but i want to know how can i save no. of trails used by user ,as if i would use **shared preference** or **local database** ,then after **uninstalling** the app ,every think will be delete and user can use trails again after installing again. I can do this using online server ,but my client does not have a server. my question is can we do this using **in app billing server**? .means store the data on this server ,without showing the popup and show popup after 10.In app purchase in new to me. i have search a lot but did not get what i want.please suggest me some think so that i can full fill my client requirement.